# IndexError: list index out of range while accessing the index in 'for' loop

Tags: python

I couldn't figure out why getting this error though it shows no error if I put `count = 1` under the second for loop but not what I expect as `count` is being set again `1` even though implemented every time just before ending the loop which makes no sense.

I wrote on user input: `MF MF` (for example)

```
test_case = int(input())

for x in range(test_case):
    my_list = input().split()
    count = 1
    for each_element in my_list:
        if each_element == len(my_list): 
            if each_element[1] == my_list[0][0]: 
                temp = 1
                break
        else:
            to_compare = my_list[count]
            if each_element[1] == to_compare[0]:
                temp = 1
                break
            else:
                temp = 0
        count += 1
    print("LOOP" if temp == 0 else "NO LOOP")
```

Comment: your count should start from 0 its starting from 1

Comment: I tried to compare 0 block with 1 block of that list that's why